# Names of Days in Islam

Tags: islamic-basis

I have heard of the names of Islamic months which are:

- Muharram
- Safar
- Rabi-al-Awwal
- Rabi-al-Thani
- Jumada-al-Awwal
- Jumada-al-Thani
- Rajab
- Shaban
- Ramadan
- Shawwal
- Zul-Qaadah
- Zul-Hijjah

But the question arises that if there are names of months in Islam then why aren't their names of days in Islam. I know for Friday is Al-Jummah but I don't know about the rest. Are there names for days in Islam?

Comment: This is somewhat relevant [Was the name friday jumu'a known before Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28459/was-the-name-friday-jumua-known-before-islam)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already mentioned in the comments days in the week don't have specific names, rather they are indicated with numbers ranging from 1- 7 beginning with Sunday.

> يَوم الأحَد    (Yawm Al-Ahad)    - Sunday
>
> يَوم الإثنين  (Yawm Al-Ithnayn) - Monday
>
> يَوم الثلاثاء (Yawm Atthulata)  - Tuesday
>
> يَوم الأربعاء (Yawm Al-arbi'a)  - Wednesday
>
> يَوم الخميس  (Yawm Al-Khamees) - Thursday
>
> يَوم الجمعة  (Yawm Al-Jumu'a)  - Friday
>
> يَوم السبت   (Yawm Assabt)     - Saturday

Comment: <comments deleted> comments are meant for clarification!

Comment: want to talk in chat Anonymous I?

Answer (score 1):

There are names of months in Islam because the Islamic calendar started with the event of Hijrah. There was also a need to mark the special months:

> They ask you concerning the new moons (Literally: crescents). Say,
>   "They are fixed times for mankind, and (for) the Pilgrimage." ... **(Surah Al-Baqarah, 189)**

Because existing methods were being misused:

> Indeed, the postponing
>   [of restriction within sacred months] is an increase in disbelief by
>   which those who have disbelieved are led [further] astray. They make
>   it lawful one year and unlawful another year to correspond to the
>   number made unlawful by Allah and [thus] make lawful what Allah has
>   made unlawful. Made pleasing to them is the evil of their deeds; and
>   Allah does not guide the disbelieving people. **(Surah Al-Tawbah,37)**

As for days, they already had their names in Arabic version. Only one of the days of week is special and is marked i.e., Al-Jummah(Friday).

You could refer [Islamic new year beginning in Muharram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35673/islamic-new-year-beginning-in-muharram/37212#37212) to know more about the starting of Islamic calendar.

Comment: thx for the answer so I just upvoted u!